# .height() is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my function that makes two div the same height:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                         var subMenuArray=document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
                         for(i=0;i<subMenuArray.length;i++)
                         {
                             var leftPart=subMenuArray[i].getElementsByClassName("submenu_category_div");
                             var rightPart=subMenuArray[i].getElementsByClassName("hot_sale_product_div");
                             var leftHeight = leftPart[i].height();
                             var rightHeight = rightPart[i].height();

                            if (leftHeight > rightHeight){
                                rightPart[0].setAttribute('height', leftHeight );
                            }
                            else{
                                leftPart[0].setAttribute('height', rightHeight);
                            }
                        };


});
```

But it says that height is not a function in:

```
var leftHeight = leftPart[0].height();
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: You misspelled height the second time `leftPart[0].heigth()` <--

Comment: Native DOM [`Element`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) don't have a `.height()` method defined. If you'd like to use jQuery's [`.height()` method](http://api.jquery.com/height/), you'll have to create a [`jQuery` collection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) -- `$(leftPart).height()`. Or, use native defined properties like [`.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks,your answer work,but I got 0 and I'm figuring why

Comment: @CheuckKwanLee You don't have to remove the use of `getElementsByClass()`. You can create a `jQuery` collection [from an element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element) you already have -- `$(leftPart).height()`. Or, if you'd like to use jQuery from the top, you can replace `getElementsByClassName` by providing it with a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) -- `$('.submenu').each(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

Spelling error. heigth !== height.

```
var leftHeight = leftPart[i].height();
```

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: any console errors? @CheuckKwanLee

Comment: @CheuckKwanLee can you explain `It still doesn't work ` ?

Comment: @JSantosh I corrected it but it still doesn't work and Jonathan Lonowski has pointed out the problem

Comment: This answer is wrong. see @Jonathan Lonowski's comment for the correct answer above. 5 up votes ????

Comment: @BG101 I did typed wrong at the beginning and I corrected after that but this is not the reason. Your right. Jonathan Lonowski's comment solved my problem.